# Problems with ESP32 interrupts connected to MCP23017

Tags: interrupt, esp32, interrupt-handling

I have a problem and I have not been able to get out of it for months. I am trying to manage the lights, I would like to control 8 relays with 8 buttons, the system works but using the interrupt I can not stabilize the program.

So if I repeatedly press the buttons the sketch stops, maybe the problem is my wrong way to use IRAM, the configuration is the following: ESP32 connected with I2C with MCP23017 and under the Sketch, could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#include "Adafruit_MCP23017.h"
#include <SPI.h>

byte IntPin = 23; // collegare entrata interrupt mcp A------------------------
volatile boolean awakenByInterrupt = false;
static uint16_t ledState = 0;
boolean led_state[8];
byte pinLed[] = {7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
byte buttons[] = {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
int i;
  
void IRAM_ATTR intCallBack() {
  awakenByInterrupt = true;
}
    
Adafruit_MCP23017 mcp;
    
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  mcp.begin();
  pinMode(IntPin, INPUT);
  for (i = 0; i < (8); i++) {
    mcp.pinMode(buttons[i], INPUT);
    mcp.pinMode(pinLed[i], OUTPUT);
    mcp.pullUp(buttons[i], HIGH); //------------------- da valutare
    mcp.digitalWrite(pinLed[i], LOW);
    led_state[i] = false;
    mcp.setupInterruptPin(buttons[i], RISING);
  }
  mcp.readGPIOAB();
  mcp.setupInterrupts(true, false, LOW);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(IntPin), intCallBack, FALLING);
}
    
void handleInterrupt() { // gestione pulsanti da interrupt************************************************************************************
  uint8_t pin = mcp.getLastInterruptPin();
  //uint8_t val = mcp.getLastInterruptPinValue();
  led_state[pin - 8] = ! led_state[pin - 8];
  if (led_state[pin - 8]) 
    mcp.digitalWrite(pinLed[pin - 8], HIGH);
  else 
    mcp.digitalWrite(pinLed[pin - 8], LOW);

  while (!(!mcp.digitalRead(buttons[0]) && ! mcp.digitalRead(buttons[1]) &&  !mcp.digitalRead(buttons[2]) && !mcp.digitalRead(buttons[3]) && !mcp.digitalRead(buttons[4]) && !mcp.digitalRead(buttons[5]) && !mcp.digitalRead(buttons[6]) && !mcp.digitalRead(buttons[7])));
  mcp.readGPIOAB();
  awakenByInterrupt = false;
}
   
void loop() {
  if (awakenByInterrupt)
    handleInterrupt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

change:
`while (!(!mcp.digitalRead(buttons[0]) && ! mcp.digitalRead(buttons[1]) &&  !mcp.digitalRead(buttons[2]) && !mcp.digitalRead(buttons[3]) && !mcp.digitalRead(buttons[4]) && !mcp.digitalRead(buttons[5]) && !mcp.digitalRead(buttons[6]) && !mcp.digitalRead(buttons[7]))); mcp.readGPIOAB();`

with:
`while (!(mcp.digitalRead(buttons[0]) && mcp.digitalRead(buttons[1]) &&  mcp.digitalRead(buttons[2]) && mcp.digitalRead(buttons[3]) && mcp.digitalRead(buttons[4]) && mcp.digitalRead(buttons[5]) && mcp.digitalRead(buttons[6]) && mcp.digitalRead(buttons[7])));`